# Yodlee: In developer portal, clicking "Fastlink" for test user throws error

Tags: yodlee

On the API dashboard in the developer portal, I clicked "Fastlink For aggregation" for the "test user". It opens a window and then throws error

> An error occurred while processing the request or session is invalid.

This has previously worked for me including the sample code. When I execute the sample code now, I could see the Json has the following error when login in the testuser -

```
{"errorCode": "Y002", "referenceCode": "b1488467077320P4e27Y", "errorMessage": "Invalid loginName/password"}
```

I created a new user in Yodlee and tried the same. But still the same error. I have also tried the same in firefox and not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to launch FL2 in API dashboard for other users.

In case if you have unregistered a user and trying to launch FL2 for that unregistered user(in API dashboard) then you will receive the above error.

Please note: Always ensure to use the latest userSession token(rSession) and Token to launch FL2.
If the session tokens are not the latest, then also you will get error.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Krithik